# Jquery cbpFWSlider in magento not working in only chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, google-chrome, slider

I discovered partway through finishing the cbpFWSlider on the site that it doesn't want to run in chrome at all. I've no idea why. All i know is that i've had to set no conflict for jquery in order to run scripts correctly on this version of magento. Not only that, however there are several other scripts in this site. However, i've taken them out and tried the slider on its own and it still doesn't want to run. At all.

The only thing i've managed to deduce is this.

http://puu.sh/5qlyj

The console on chrome shows a duplicate of the transform instead of a 3d transform... and i have no idea why. I've been through everything and all i can work out is that it stems from this line somehow.

```
if( this.support ) {
this.$list.css( 'transform', this.support3d ? 'translate3d(' + translateVal + '%,0,0)' : 'translate(' + translateVal + '%)' );
}
else {
this.$list.css( 'margin-left', -1 * this.current * 100 + '%' ); 
}
```

The site in question can be found here. http://tinyurl.com/pgwxlbr

If anyone could help me with this, i would be greatly appreciative! It's a long shot posting on here, but i've had great luck before!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I still have no idea WHY chrome insisted on not reading this correctly, but by adding a second line exclusive to webkit within the toggle nav controls.

```
if( this.support ) {
this.$list.css( 'transform', this.support3d ? 'translate3d(' + translateVal + '%,0,0)' : 'translate(' + translateVal + '%)' );
//new line a duplicate of above, except using the webkit format
this.$list.css( '-webkit-transform', this.support3d ? 'translate3d(' + translateVal + '%,0,0)' : 'translate(' + translateVal + '%)' );
}
```